# Injecting a service in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

How do I inject a service into the controller and domain?

I am very new to grails and can't find this info online.

Comment: [It's explained in the "service layer" chapter of the user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#dependencyInjectionServices)

Answer (score 8):

In Controller

```
def springSecurityService
```

and in Domain

```
transient springSecurityService
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

Try this.

Answer (score 4):

Dependency Injection in Grails is like autowired by default "Convention Over Configuration".
The configuration dictates that if you have defined your service class inside.

> rightclick > new groovy class > give a name like SourceService.groovy.

under this folder and subfolders

> yourapplication / services / SourceService.groovy

will look like :

```
class SourceService {

def serviceMethod(){

//do some work here
}

}
```

folder , the configuration will handle that this used as dependency injection bean as ordinary bean definition of spring and struts applications.

When you come to use it :

You always have to declare a variable of the SourceService as `camelCase` same as it SourceService.groovy file under /services folder. Ok.

Let say if you want to call a service in your domain or controller class.

```
def sourceService  //most usual method // see name as same as service class

SourceService sourceService // or this way as suggested on this post 

def  login(){

//the use your service with no other requirements
sourceService.serviceMethod() // bam!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection can be done by using def and serviceName but I would recommend using static types.

If you have a UserService then in your controller's, domain's and other services you should use

```
UserService userService
```

This will give you advantage of Groovy's static type checking and speed, which will save you from wasting your time for debugging, testing in future.

Basically it is like if you know the types use those static types if you dont know go with def.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is done automatically for you by grails using Spring Dependency Injection - so all you need to do is define the bean (the name of your service) in the controller / domain file using:

```
def serviceName
```

You can then call service methods from this object. Click here to read more in the official grails docs:
[here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html#dependencyInjectionServices)